# Jetpack Compose forgets a remembered value when switching tabs

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm trying to learn Jetpack Compose multiplatform in Kotlin. Below is a minimal, compilable example:

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(){
    var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Checkbox(checked, {checked = !checked})
}

@Composable
fun TabContainer() {
    var index by mutableStateOf(0)
    val tabs = listOf("Tab A", "Tab B")
    MaterialTheme {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            TabRow(index) {
                tabs.forEachIndexed { i, title ->
                    Tab(index == i, { index = i }, text = { Text(title) })
                }
            }
            when (index) { 0 -> TestScreen() }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application { TabContainer() }
```

As you can see, the checkbox in TestScreen is checked by default. I want it to remain unchecked when I come back to it after switching a tab. However, it reverts to being checked when I switch to Tab B and back. Is the only way to solve this a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `checked state` move to upper compose?

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    Checkbox(
        checked = checked,
        onCheckedChange = {
            onCheckedChange(it)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun TabContainer() {
    var index by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val tabs = listOf("Tab A", "Tab B")

    var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    MaterialTheme {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            TabRow(index) {
                tabs.forEachIndexed { i, title ->
                    Tab(index == i, { index = i }, text = { Text(title) })
                }
            }
            when (index) {
                0 -> TestScreen(
                    checked = checked,
                    onCheckedChange = {
                        checked = !checked
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't think of that, thanks. I don't know what you mean by "checked state" move so I'll assume it's moving the variables into the parent scope. However, I'll have at least 6 such variables (for a configuration), so it'll probably get a bit messy unless I wrap everything under a single var, which would be slightly less readable. Is there no other way?

Comment: You can consolidate your states into a single data class or separate them into distinct data classes based on requirements, and then store them in your ViewModel. It might enhance code readability if you relocate them to the top rather than handling them separately within each compose function. Certainly, operations can still be executed in specific compose functions as necessary, in which case the ViewModel itself needs to be passed. However, I believe that adding and passing view model states as parameters will improve your code's clarity and organization.